# .net standard 2.0 and third party libraries

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I have read some on .net standard e.g. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Nov/23/NET-Standard-20-Making-Sense-of-NET-Again and am still a bit confused on upgrading an existing full framework to .net core 2.0 using standard 2.0.
My question is if a third party library does not support .net standard 2.0 is this an issues.
For example I have an application that uses JSON.net and log4net where the first supports standard 2.0 but second only supports 1.3

Comment: The lower the version number, the more platforms it supports.  So 1.3 is "better" than 2.0.  Did you try it?